# How to check the answer in a quiz?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a sortable list to rearrange the words to make a meaningful sentence. I am unable to figure out why the alert in checking the answer section is not working. This is not working: alert('success');

https://codepen.io/Tarun1980/pen/ZNdJze

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var words = [];
var i = 0;
function showWords() {
    $('#container').append("<ul id='list'></ul>");
    for (var j = 0; j < words[i].question.length; j++) {
        $('#list').append("<li class='box' id=" + words[i].question[j] + ">" + words[i].question[j] + " " + "</li>");
    }

    $('#list').sortable({
        placeholder: 'back',
        axis: 'x',
        opacity: '0.7'
    });
}
showWords();


$(document).on('click', '#btn', function () {
    var guess = $('.box').text();
    $('#list').empty();
    if (i < words.length); {
        var correct = words[i].answer;
        i++;
        showWords();
    }
    if (guess === correct) {
        alert('success');
    }
});
```

});

Comment: `var answer = "";
$("#list").each(function(i,li){ answer += $(li).text() + " " });
answer = answer.replace(/[\n\r\t\s+]/g," ").trim();
alert(answer);`

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line breaks within HTML are considered text-nodes, consisting of a single space. It explains why this...

```
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>World</li>
</ul>
```

...renders as `"Hello World "` despite having no spaces in it.

As such, your `guess` has a trailing space due to the line break between the final `</li>` and the `</ul>`.

To mitigate this, simply `trim()` your guess.

```
if (guess.trim() === correct) {
  alert("success");
}
```